# Proving that any continuously differentiable functions preserve Jordan measurability of bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable and $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and Jordan measurable. Prove that $f(U)$ is also Jordan measurable.

I know that  any bounded set is Jordan measurable iff its boundary is of measure $0$ and any continuously differentiable function maps sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$. Then I wanted to show that the boundary of $f(U)$ is contained in  the image of the boundary of $U$, i.e. $\partial f(U)\subset f(\partial U)$.

But in this problem, $f$ is only continuously differentiable. I got stuck in carrying out this idea. Any hints? Thanks in advance!

**Added**

Put $M=\{x:\det Jf (x)=0\}$.

I realized that it suffices to prove that $f(M)$ is of measure $0$, which looks like a conclusion of sard theorem.

But in this case $f$ is only $C^1$. Then I tried the following

For $x\in M$, it's known that
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{m(f(B(x,r)))}{m(B(x,r))}=0$$
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Given $\varepsilon$. Then for each $x\in M$, we can choose $r_x$ such that $\frac{m(f(B(x,r)))}{m(B(x,r))} \le \varepsilon$ for all $r\le r_x$.

There exists an open cover $\bigcup_{x\in M} B(x,r_x)$. Considering that $M$ is compact, we know that there exists a subcover $\bigcup_{1}^N B(x_i,r_{x_i})$. Then we have
$$m(f(M))\le \varepsilon \sum_1^N m( B(x_i,r_{x_i}))$$

But how can we show that $\varepsilon \sum_1^N m( B(x_i,r_{x_i}))$ can be arbitrarily small? Can we find a subcover such that  $\sum_1^N m( B(x_i,r_{x_i}))\le C$ where $C$ is a constant  independent of $\varepsilon$? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625535/show-continuously-differentiable-image-of-jordan-measurable-set-is-jordan-measur/2632208

Comment: @Reveillark I've seen that post. But in that one we also assume that $f$ is injective

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), Sard's theorem does apply here, when $f$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Your idea $\partial f(U)\subseteq f(\partial U)$ doesn't work. For example: $$n=1,\quad f:x\mapsto x^2$$ $$U=[-2,1]\mapsto f(U)=[0,4]$$ $$\partial U=\{-2,1\}\mapsto f(\partial U)=\{4,1\}$$ $$\partial f(U)=\{0,4\}\not\subseteq f(\partial U)$$